# Does Rust implement From<Vec<T>> for Vec<U> if I have already implemented From<T> for U?

Tags: generics, vector, rust, traits, parametric-polymorphism

I have a struct `NotificationOption` and another struct `NotificationOption2` as well as an implementation for `From<NotificationOption>` for `NotificationOption2`.

I'm would like to convert `Vec<NotificationOption>` to a `Vec<NotificationOption2>`:

```
struct NotificationOption {
    key: String,
}

struct NotificationOption2 {
    key: String,
}

impl From<NotificationOption> for NotificationOption2 {
    fn from(n: NotificationOption) -> Self {
        Self {
            key: n.key,
        }
    }
}

let options: Vec<NotificationOption> = ...;
let options2: Vec<NotificationOption2> = options.into();
```

But I get a compiler error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Vec<NotificationOption2>: From<Vec<NotificationOption>>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:22:46
   |
22 |     let options2: Vec<NotificationOption2> = options.into();
   |                                              ^^^^^^^ ---- required by a bound introduced by this call
   |                                              |
   |                                              the trait `From<Vec<NotificationOption>>` is not implemented for `Vec<NotificationOption2>`
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=43a7247909ab2ba777e897adcbad8305)

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't, but it's trivial to implement yourself:

```rust
let options2: Vec<NotificationOption2> = options.into_iter().map(|x| x.into()).collect();
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems not, and it makes sense - you assume that the conversion from `Vec<NotificationOption>` to `Vec<NotificationOption2>` is to create a `Vec<NotificationOption2>`, convert the `NotificationOption` items into `NotificationOption2` using `.into()` and add them to the vector. Rust has no reason to assume this is *the* conversion and not some other routine.

You also can't implement `From` generically for a Vec to Vec since your crate didn't define `From`. You can perhaps create a conversion trait of your own, and implement it generically between `Vec<X: Into<Y>>` and `Vec<Y>`.

Comment: But the conversion that OP describes is the simplest one that doesn't drop elements. I think that is reason enough to call it the canonical one.

Comment: If Rust automagically provides this conversion, it disallows developers to write their custom conversions.

Comment: You can suggest it in an RFC but i doubt it'll gain support

Comment: @MAHanin - You can't write your own anyway, because of the [orphan rule](https://github.com/Ixrec/rust-orphan-rules). [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2fea6336302baa181509171e17c77733)

Comment: what about From<Option<T>> for Option<U> ? seems like a lot of boiler plate for repitition no?

Comment: You can always write a generic helper function to help you conduct such conversions, saving you the boilerplates. Or a macro maybe. It isn't as nice as having it implemented via trait, but it is something. I do see the temptation in implementing all these conversions in the standard library, I just think it may be rejected on grounds of purity. But I do encourage you to try and RFC it, so wiser people will consider it and comment.